# Ubuntu 22.04: ALL browsers crash after update

Tags: 22.04, firefox, google-chrome, chromium, brave

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop since 1 year. It works with me like a charm. Suddenly, after I have updated the system one month ago, ALL browsers (chromium, google chrome stable, Firefox, gnome-web, brave) crash randomly. I have tried all possible solutions like disable GPU, disable hardware acceleration, clear GPUCache, working in incognito-mode, and even booting from older kernels (v5.15 instead of 6.2), but nothing works.

Any help?

@user535733:

Yes. Using **ls -l**  command:

```
$ ls -l /var/crash

-rw-r-----  1 user   whoopsie 61098551 Nov 15 14:06 _opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.crash

-rw-r-----  1 gdm    whoopsie  5456780 Nov 10 14:58 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.127.crash

-rw-r-----  1 user   whoopsie 16966116 Nov 15 20:41 _usr_bin_nautilus.1000.crash

-rw-r-----  1 user  whoopsie  8934483 Nov 16 06:37 _usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_webkit2gtk-4.1_WebKitNetworkProcess.1000.crash
```

Comment: Do the crashes result in .crash files created in /var/crash?

Comment: Silly answer but: you should try running a memtest to overrule bad ram.

Comment: @MatiasNGoldberg   According to https://itslinuxfoss.com/run-memtest-ubuntu-22-04/, the output of **memtest** did not give any abnormal results.